# Sharepoint Calculated Date Value

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've used this formula in my calculated column to indicate the date for 10 past the `SENT` date entered.  It returns the date fine, but in other records without a date inserted it returns a value of `1/9/1900`.

How can I add to this formula to leave the record blank if `SENT` is null?

```
=TEXT(Sent+10,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [SharePoint Calculated Column Formulas](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/). Your formula should be similar to this:

```
=IF(Sent <> "", TEXT(Sent+10,"mm/dd/yyyy"), "")
```

(I didn't test it)